# xpath get parent anywhere in the document and all of its childs with or without namespaces with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

XML WITHOUT NAMEPSACES:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <title>XML WITHOUT NAMESPACES</title>
    <entry>
        <price>67 EUR</price>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

XML WITH NAMEPSACES:

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>XML WITH NAMESPACES</title>
        <entry>
            <g:price>67.00</g:price>
        </entry>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

My code:

`$product_nodes = $xml_file->xpath("//*[local-name()='entry']");`

**section of var_dump:**
XML WITHOUT NAMESPACES ON CHILDS:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#374 (12) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "67 EUR"
```

XML WITH NAMESPACES ON CHILDS:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#376 (0) { } [1]=> 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#371 (0) { } [2]=>
```

How to retrieve nodes with namespace same as nodes without namespace?

Comment: What exactly do you want back from the code, if you try using `echo $product_nodes[0]->asXML();` it will show the actual contents of the selected node itself.

Comment: I feel your pain, and believe that name spaces are overkill in many cases.  I'd suggest running the XML through a XSL transform to remove the namespaces.  BTW, your first example actually has a "default" namespace without a prefix, to use XPath, you'll need to declare that namespace.

Comment: echo $product_nodes[0]->asXML(); gives Undefined offset: 0

Comment: If it's undefined after `$product_nodes = $xml_file->xpath(...`, then no nodes where found.

Comment: Sorry, with the xml with namespace var_dump($product_nodes[0]->asXML()); gives '67'  that is ok, but now how i can do $product->price = something_else to change the price in the document?